# Confused about classes Python

Tags: python, list, class, sorting, natural-sort

I am a bit confused on how classes work in python.

I wanted to sort an input in a natural way and found this solution:

```
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

alist=[
    "something1",
    "something12",
    "something17",
    "something2",
    "something25",
    "something29"]

alist.sort(key=natural_keys)
```

Works like a charm.

Now I wanted to include the solution in my class.

```
class __test():

    def atoi(self,text):

        return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

    def natural_keys(self,text):

        return [ self.atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

b = __test()

alist=[
    "something1",
    "something12",
    "something17",
    "something2",
    "something25",
    "something29"]

alist.sort(key=b.natural_keys(alist))
```

Which does not work since alist is given to natural keys as a list

This works like a charm:

```
class __test():

    def atoi(self,text):

        return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

    def natural_keys(self,text):

        return [ self.atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

    def sorta(self,input):

        a = input[::]

        a.sort(key=natural_keys)

        return a


b = __test()

alist=[
    "something1",
    "something12",
    "something17",
    "something2",
    "something25",
    "something29"]

print b.sorta(alist)
```

I can sort of understand that I have to do the sorta() def since everything is inside the class and from the outside it is not known.

But why can I not call it like the first try?
How does the input to natural_keys end up as a list in my first try but not in the second?

Another question is why can I not do this:

```
   def sorta(self,input):

       return input.sort(key=natural_keys)
```

Thx in advance.
Sorry if my wording seems confusing but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Why would you *want * to put it in a class? Note that you access methods like attributes: `key=self.natural_keys`.

Comment: "key" is supposed to be a function that takes a list element as an argument.  Your second example would work if you put b.natural_keys.

Comment: In your final example: `a.sort(key=natural_keys)` should not work at all, because "natural_keys" was never created.  I'm guessing that the reason it did work is that your ran it in the same interpreter session as your first example.  `a.sort(key=self.natural_keys)` should work.

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe: I wanted to put it in the class because it would be used inside that class and nowhere else. Thought it would look more organized this way.

Comment: @peter True. I thought I tried that one and it didn't work. But its like always if you start playing around sometimes you forget what you have tried. The second example works now. And True to the final example. It was the same interpreter session. Stupid mistake. I have not programmed in python for over a year. It seems I do some of the newbie mistakes again...